# Group policy doesn't let me execute Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, group-policy

Where I work, the admins just migrated us to Windows 7. They gave me admin rights but still, I had to "Run as Administrator" my Google Chrome installation.

After I managed to install it, I realized I even have to go through the "Run as Administrator" shortcut every time I have to execute the application. I even edited the properties of the shortcut to check "Always run as Administrator" but nothing changed.

The message I get when I'm trying to launch Chrome is "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information contact your system administrator"...

Is it something I could work out alone or I have to convince them to change the "policy"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard Chrome installation installs to the user profile. It sounds like the administrators at your location have setup AppLocker to restrict launches of programs from the user profile space.

To fix this, remove Chrome and download/install the Chrome MSI which correctly places Chrome in the Program Files directory on your PC ([download link](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/browser/))

Comment: I downloaded the msi, I run it, but after the loading screen there's nothing happening.. I guess it is equally blocked somehow. I also can't "run as administrator" the .msi ...

Comment: it's ok I had to uninstall the previous version! works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Regarding the not being able to Run As Administrator on an MSI, this is a limitation of MSIs in general, you cannot elevate via UAC an MSI by clicking its icon.  Only by running it from an elevated CMD window.